Django mysql icontains not working for small case
When I type Travel exactly same as my database it's working but when type travel it's working even I tried icontains for ignore case sensitivity. my code:
similar_titles_query = Q(title__icontains=search_query) & Q(parent_product__isnull=True, domain_name=domain_name,is_published=False)
similar_titles_results = Product.objects.filter(similar_titles_query).order_by('?')[:5]


What is the collation of the database, table and title column?

@willeM icontains working after I change my mysql db to utf8mb4_general_ci

This is (was) not really a Django issue: Django generates a query, but it depends on the database what it does with that query.
Often when string matching does not work correctly, this is due to the collation of the database, or a specific collation of the table or column.
You thus might want to change the collation to an encoding that can work with case-insensitive matching.
